# Maps that can aid the locations of the cities referenced in Masechet Gittin?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, geography, maseches-gitin, cities

I’m currently learning Masechet Gittin and would like to know where I can find maps of the cities referenced in the first daf or so that can assist me. Cities like heger, rekem, kfar lud, etc is what I’m trying to find.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94082/16706 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89402/16706

Comment: I usually see people draw their own maps based on Rashi etc. as a visual aid. Do you mean geographic location?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It’s quite funny that you cited the Obermeyer question you posted last year, I saw that one question a few hours ago. Anyway I understand pshat through Rashi’s explanation. I’ve just wanted to know if any there were any maps that would show precise locations of those cities.

Comment: There is a book called aid to Talmud study which has a beautiful map appendix.

Comment: From what I remember Encyclopedia Talmudica has some maps that cover this, either under "get" or "eretz yisrael".